# SQL How to make inner join query from sentences table to itself using linking table

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have 2 tables

```
sentences 
-----------
id | lang | sentence
```

```
links 
-------------
sentence_id | translation_id
```

I've tried to do something like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM sentences_unicode AS s
INNER JOIN links AS l ON l.sentence_id = s.id
INNER JOIN sentences_unicode AS t ON l.translation_id = t.id
WHERE s.lang = 'pol' AND s.sentence LIKE "%pasek%"
```

But this doesn't work. I tought it is correct, but this seems to timeout. Maybe because there are several millions of sentences. Is there any other way to get
sentences and their translations for given search conditions ?

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #2006 - MySQL server has gone away

```
mysql> DESCRIBE links;
+----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| sentence_id    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| translation_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |


mysql> DESCRIBE sentences_unicode;
+----------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type           | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id       | int(11)        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| lang     | varchar(3)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| sentence | varchar(15000) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

I can only execute single INNER JOIN and it tooks about 26 sec
I've tried this

```
SELECT * 
FROM sentences_unicode AS s
INNER JOIN links AS l ON l.sentence_id = s.id
WHERE s.lang = 'pol' AND MATCH (s.sentence) AGAINST ('pasek' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

Comment: Publish table definitions so we can see indexes,engines and collations

Answer (score 0):

If your query times out it's not a syntax error, it's a performance problem.

Like with `'%search%'` it's the slowest possible! If you have an index on the `sentence` column, searches  `LIKE 'pasek%'` will be faster but will not search inside the string, only strings that start with `pasek`.

You can optimize by creating a `FULLTEXT index` on the `sentence` column.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html

```
SELECT * 
FROM sentences_unicode AS s
INNER JOIN links AS l ON l.sentence_id = s.id
INNER JOIN sentences_unicode AS t ON l.translation_id = t.id
WHERE s.lang = 'pol' AND MATCH (sentence) AGAINST ('pasek') IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE
```

In MySQL versions, prior to 5.6.4, `Full-Text search` was only available on MyISAM tables. With the general phasing out of MyISAM, InnoDB full-text search (FTS) is finally available since MySQL 5.6.4

Also, you should **create indexes on the columns you use in the joins**: `sentence_id`, `translation_id`, etc. It would have been useful the see the table definitions.

Comment: I've tried but it sill takes to many time I think. Above solution with single inner join took 26 sec. I think I have too many sentences > 7mln but others to this in milliseconds but probably differently, maybe there use othere databases than MySQL

Comment: Probably I should do this search in steps it would be much I think it would be much faster

Comment: I updated the answer. Do you have indexes on the columns you use in the inner join? This is the first bottleneck if you don't.